# Can heap corruption be caused by linking issues?

Tags: c++, access-violation, heap-corruption

I am getting an access violation in my program when running some code that belongs to a library. My program statically links to the library. I'm able to run that code in other projects without issues, but for some reason it crashes in my program. I put the code at the very beginning of the program to ensure no other code has been executed and it still crashes. I don't think it's an issue with the library since that runs fine in other contexts. I have no idea why it's crashing and I've been trying to figure it out for two weeks now. Here is the more detailed post I've copied to the library's github page:

I'm trying to use the http_listener in an MFC project built in visual studio 2017 with platform toolset v141. It runs fine until executing the code that links to the cpprestsdk. The cpprestsdk was installed using vcpkg, which built the cpprestsdk using the vc141 platform toolset.

My project has no known preexisting heap corruption issues, so the fact that this is causing a heap corruption is confusing.

Here is the offending line of code:

```
BOOL CAuthenticationServerApp::InitInstance()
{
    CWinApp::InitInstance();

    utility::string_t port = U("34568");
    utility::string_t address = U("http://127.0.0.1:");
    address.append(port);

    web::uri_builder uri(address);

    auto addr = uri.to_uri().to_string();
---->std::unique_ptr<http_listener> listener = std::make_unique<http_listener>(addr);
    listener->open().wait();
    ...
```

The first thing my program executes is this code. There is no other code before it, so nothing that would potentially cause a corrupted heap, so I'm thinking it has something to do with the library itself.

Error message:

> Exception thrown at 0x005B90F8 in AuthenticationServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0B39D000.
>   Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.

Here is the call stack where the exception is being thrown. It's crashing when trying to declare a variable in the http_listener_impl contsructor:

```
    AuthenticationServer.exe!std::_Ptr_base<Concurrency::details::_Task_impl<unsigned char> >::_Ptr_base<Concurrency::details::_Task_impl<unsigned char> >() Line 1158  C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!std::shared_ptr<Concurrency::details::_Task_impl<unsigned char> >::shared_ptr<Concurrency::details::_Task_impl<unsigned char> >(void * __formal) Line 1277 C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!Concurrency::task<unsigned char>::task<unsigned char>() Line 2963  C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!Concurrency::task<void>::task<void>() Line 3985    C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!web::http::experimental::listener::details::http_listener_impl::http_listener_impl(web::uri address) Line 58   C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!utility::details::make_unique<web::http::experimental::listener::details::http_listener_impl,web::uri>(web::uri && arg1) Line 389  C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!web::http::experimental::listener::http_listener::http_listener(web::uri address) Line 222 C++
    [External Code] 
    AuthenticationServer.exe!CAuthenticationServerApp::InitInstance() Line 79   C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 37   C++
    AuthenticationServer.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 26  C++
    [External Code]
```

This code actually runs fine if I place it in a new MFC project or another similar sized MFC project. Is it possible that there's an issue with the library, or is it something to do with my code? The program does have some global variables, which I checked, and none of them contain code that allocates or frees memory on the heap in their constructors. So I don't know how the heap is getting corrupted. The project links to a few other libraries, and I've ensured that they were all built using the same platform toolset. The libraries have no known issues and have been used for years. I've placed the http_listener code in another project that is almost identical to this one, with the same dependencies and it runs fine.

Comment: Can you tell us about the library, how you're invoking it, your linker, and your linking parameters/process?

Comment: well, here is the full link to the issue. I posted it on the github page for the library that I'm using. https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/issues/1092

Comment: Would you be able to edit the most relevant portions of this directly into your post body? Stack Overflow questions should be useful on their own, even if linked resources become unavailable for any reason such as link rot.

Comment: Sure, I can just copy the github post into here

Comment: I've definitely seen heap corruption as a result of linking code compiled with compiler version A together with object files or libraries compiled with compiler version B.  In my case, it would happen when code compiled with compiler version A would allocate an object, and then code compiled with compiler version B would later free the object (my guess is that some statically-included memory-heap implementation details had changed between the two compiler versions).  If you have the option of compiling everything from source (rather than relying on supplied object files), I recommend it.

Comment: Well, I've compiled the program and all of its dependencies with the same Visual Studio 2017 compiler to attempt to rule that out.

Comment: If your code includes a header file from a different version than that of the library, then it can easily cause a crash. Maybe you placed a newer/older header file in a directory of your project by accident? If there is a different http_listener declaration there, then all bets are off

Comment: My project is using the include files from C:\Users\aprole\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows-static\include\cpprest and the linker is using fully qualified paths to link to the dependencies in vcpkg\installed\x86-windows-static\debug\lib. So there's no mismatch between header files and library files

Comment: I guess the question should be how do I know if this is an issue with the library, an issue with my code, or a linking issue? I have no reason to believe it's a linking issue. And since the code is executing right at the beginning of my program, not much has happened besides creating some global variables and the MFC framework stuff, could not find anything there that would corrupt the heap. So maybe it's an issue with the library itself?